# Regex - select all text that does not start with a specific number

Tags: regex

I want to get all text that does not start with 1,2,12,34.
I wrote

```
^((?!1|2|12|34).)*$
```

(^ asserts position at start of a line)
as in:

https://regex101.com/r/gI6sN8/14

Problems

- It also doesn't select text that has 1 or 2 in the middle ("AB 1 CD").
- It also doesn't select 13 (because it starts with 1)

How can I restrict it

Comment: i think its positioning of **[`parenthesis`](https://regex101.com/r/gI6sN8/15)**

Comment: also you need **[`\b`](https://regex101.com/r/gI6sN8/17)**

Comment: By "get", do you mean "match"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want this:

```
^(?!(1|2|12|34)\s).*
```

https://regex101.com/r/gI6sN8/16

Comment: Excellent
btw, what does \s do?

Comment: It enforces a space after the number to prevent `1` from matching`13` (for example)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comment, you need word boundary and correct parenthesis position

```
^(?!(?:1|2|12|34)\b)(.*)$
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gI6sN8/18)**

You can also use `\D`

```
^(?!(?:1|2|12|34)\D)(.*)$
```

In your regex

```
^((?!1|2|12|34).)*$
```

you are finding whether any of the above alternative `1|2|12|34` is correct at every position. That's why it's not matching `AB 1 CD`

Comment: What does the `\b` do? I doubt if it would ever match at the beginning of the string.

Comment: Thanks, This also filters 13. which is not the action i was looking for @hek2mgl solved it.

Comment: @Jeb above solution will fail for `1: ABCD`

Comment: @Jeb i don't think it filters **[`13`](https://regex101.com/r/gI6sN8/20)**

Answer (score 1):

This works

`^(?!(?:12?|2|34)(?!\d)).+$`
https://regex101.com/r/gI6sN8/19

A valid boundary between the numbers you don't want it to
start with and the character after it appears to be any non-digit.